# Cocos2d Debugger Console Shows So many things

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, cocos2d-iphone, console

Why this happens I dont know but I am still help less....
while run my game app I found that there are So many Information About Cocos2d: in bold fonts Like this

```
 2013-04-04 13:21:02.338 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: cocos2d v0.99.5
2013-04-04 13:21:02.340 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2013-04-04 13:21:02.341 RunemanApp[280:207] Device Flag :> 0
2013-04-04 13:21:03.105 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: OS version: 4.2 (0x04020000)
2013-04-04 13:21:03.106 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2013-04-04 13:21:03.107 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2013-04-04 13:21:03.107 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
2013-04-04 13:21:03.108 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
2013-04-04 13:21:03.109 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2013-04-04 13:21:03.109 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2013-04-04 13:21:03.111 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.111 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.112 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.112 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.113 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2013-04-04 13:21:03.113 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.114 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2013-04-04 13:21:03.114 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2013-04-04 13:21:03.630 RunemanApp[280:207] Retina Display Not supported
2013-04-04 13:21:03.635 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
2013-04-04 13:21:04.364 RunemanApp[280:207] cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
[Switching to process 280]
```

Its Display while App is lunching After I play the Game Its result a lot of Lines

Its may Affect My Game speed I think .......

I am trying to reduce the result in My DEBUGGER CONSOLE Window ......

Answer (score 1):

The log you posted is what you see at launch. I'd be concerned if you logged something every frame. Even then just stop logging. Cocos2d itself doesn't log anything every frame.

Run the game in release build if you want to assess performance, since debug builds will always be somewhat slower. Release builds don't write out logs by default.

Btw, you're using a **really** old version of cocos2d from like 3 years ago. It doesn't even support iPad Retina. If you plan on publishing the app you'll have to upgrade.